# How can I remove the empty rows before saving the data?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code and the link google sheet
the problem is when I fill in the data and then click on the button Submit at PrintForm sheet the data will be saved to PrintLog sheet but it includes the empty rows
so I would like to remove the empty rows before saving that data to RpintLog sheet but I don't know how I can handle it, Looking forward to receiving your support

[image: This is the input form]

[image: This is the output]

[Link google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_ar_zOx7NaQiMdNoOGmXNCdBcxwKQPZRCrzOKfv0rLc/edit?pli=1#gid=304818981)

```
function Printting() {
  // We will add our code here. 
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // collect the data
  const sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("clearRange");
  const clearRange = sourceRange.getValues().flat();
  const SOLA_sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("SOLA");
  const SOLA_sourceVals = SOLA_sourceRange.getValues().flat();

  const SOLB_sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("SOLB");
  const SOLB_sourceVals = SOLB_sourceRange.getValues().flat();

  const SOLC_sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("SOLC");
  const SOLC_sourceVals = SOLC_sourceRange.getValues().flat();

  const SOLD_sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("SOLD");
  const SOLD_sourceVals = SOLD_sourceRange.getValues().flat();

  const SOLE_sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("SOLE");
  const SOLE_sourceVals = SOLE_sourceRange.getValues().flat();

  const SOLF_sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("SOLF");
  const SOLF_sourceVals = SOLF_sourceRange.getValues().flat();

  const SOLG_sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("SOLG");
  const SOLG_sourceVals = SOLG_sourceRange.getValues().flat();

  const SOLH_sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("SOLH");
  const SOLH_sourceVals = SOLH_sourceRange.getValues().flat();
  // Gather current dts and user email.
  const date = new Date();
  const email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  const SOLA_data = [date, email, ...SOLA_sourceVals];
  const SOLB_data = [date, email, ...SOLB_sourceVals];
  const SOLC_data = [date, email, ...SOLC_sourceVals];
  const SOLD_data = [date, email, ...SOLD_sourceVals];
  const SOLE_data = [date, email, ...SOLE_sourceVals];
  const SOLF_data = [date, email, ...SOLF_sourceVals];
  const SOLG_data = [date, email, ...SOLG_sourceVals];
  const SOLH_data = [date, email, ...SOLH_sourceVals];
  // append the data
  const destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PrintLog");
  destinationSheet.appendRow(SOLA_data);
  destinationSheet.appendRow(SOLB_data);
  destinationSheet.appendRow(SOLC_data);
  destinationSheet.appendRow(SOLD_data);
  destinationSheet.appendRow(SOLE_data);
  destinationSheet.appendRow(SOLF_data);
  destinationSheet.appendRow(SOLG_data);
  destinationSheet.appendRow(SOLH_data);
  // clear the source sheet rows
  sourceRange.clearContent();
  ss.toast("Success: Item Added to the data Log!");

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script does not detect blank rows.

The script shown below identifies the number of rows of data on `PrintForm` and uses this to set the `getRange` and `getValues`. This limits the data to ONLY rows with values and excludes any empty rows.

The OP script is idiosyncratic, and doesn't easily adapt to conversion.

**IMPORTANT:** This script assumes that there are **no blank rows** between entries on "PrintForm".

---

```
function updateLog() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var formSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PrintForm")
  var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PrintLog")

  // get the data from Form sheet
  // get the number of rows of data in Column B - SOL
  var solVals = formSheet.getRange("B6:B").getValues();
  var solLast = solVals.filter(String).length;
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the number of rows of SOL data = "+solLast)

  var dataRange = formSheet.getRange(6,2,solLast,6)
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the data range = "+dataRange.getA1Notation())
  var data = dataRange.getValues()
  
  // some email variables
  var date = new Date();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  // create a temporary array to hold the data to be pasted
  var dataArray = []
  
  // loop though the data
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var rowArray = []
    rowArray.push(date,email,data[i][0],data[i][1],data[i][2],data[i][3],data[i][4],data[i][5])
    dataArray.push(rowArray)
  }

  //Logger.log(dataArray)
  // get the last row in Log
  var logSheetLR = logSheet.getLastRow()
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the last row of data on log sheet = "+logSheetLR)
  // get the target range on the Log sheet
  var logRange = logSheet.getRange((logSheetLR+1),1,dataArray.length,8)
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the range in the log sheet = "+logRange.getA1Notation())

  // update the log sheet
  logRange.setValues(dataArray)

  // clear the source sheet rows
  dataRange.clearContent();
  ss.toast("Success: Item Added to the data Log!");
}
```

Comment: Dear Tedinoz, after I copied your script and tested it, it still can't remove the empty, for example, if I ignore row 6 at PrintForm start filling the data from row 7, and then click on the button Submit the data will be saved to the PrintLog sheet but it still has the empty row

Comment: `for example, if I ignore row 6 at PrintForm start filling the data from row 7` This is a REALLY **important** issue that should be included in the question. I have assumed (the question doesn't say otherwise) that there would be no gaps in Column B. It's not the end of the world... it's just that it requires a different formula to get the data range on Form. So... could there be gaps in the data in Column B of "Form"?

Comment: sorry, I didn't mention it at the beginning, for your question "could there be gaps in the data in Column B of "Form"?" -> yes, There will be one or more blank cells in column B

Comment: Thank you so much, Looking forward to receiving your support

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I left the original answer intact. I've added a second answer for your situation where there may be gaps (blank rows) in the Sol data on "Print Form". Fully tested, but let me know how you go.

Answer (score 1):

Your script does not detect blank rows.

The script shown below identifies the number of rows of data on PrintForm and uses this to set the getRange and getValues. This limits the data to ONLY rows with values and excludes any empty rows.

The OP script is idiosyncratic, and doesn't easily adapt to conversion.

**IMPORTANT:** This script assumes that there **are/may be blank rows** between entries on "PrintForm".

---

```
/*
* this script assumes that Sol data on "PrintForm"
* may NOT be contiguous
*/

    function updateLogNonContig() {
    
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      var formSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PrintForm")
      var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PrintLog")
    
      // get the data from Form sheet
      // get the number of rows of data in Column B - SOL
      
      var formLR = formSheet.getLastRow();
      var solVals = formSheet.getRange("B6:B"+formLR).getValues();
      var solLast  = formLR - solVals.reverse().findIndex(c=>c[0]!='');
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: Last row of SOL data = "+solLast)
      var dataRange = formSheet.getRange(6,2,(solLast-6+1),6)
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: dataRange = "+dataRange.getA1Notation())
      var data = dataRange.getValues()
    
      // some email variables
      var date = new Date();
      var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
      // create a temporary array to hold the data to be pasted
      var dataArray = []
    
      // loop though the data
      for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        if(data[i][0] ==""){
          // this row is blank, do nothing
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: Row#"+(i+6)+" is blank")
          continue
        }
        else{
          // this row is popuated so do stuff
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: Row#"+(i+6)+" is NOT blank")
          var rowArray = []
          rowArray.push(date,email,data[i][0],data[i][1],data[i][2],data[i][3],data[i][4],data[i][5])
          dataArray.push(rowArray)
        }
      }
    
      // Logger.log(dataArray) // DEBUG
    
      // get the last row in Log
      var logSheetLR = logSheet.getLastRow()
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: the last row of data on log sheet = "+logSheetLR)
      // get the target range on the Log sheet
      var logRange = logSheet.getRange((logSheetLR+1),1,dataArray.length,8)
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: the range in the log sheet = "+logRange.getA1Notation())
    
      // update the log sheet
      logRange.setValues(dataArray)
    
      // clear the source sheet rows
      dataRange.clearContent();
      ss.toast("Success: Item Added to the data Log!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to have data in your first column sheet.getLastRow() is not useful to you.  Appending rows is quite slow

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SOLA");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("SOLB");
  const sr = 5;//data start row
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, getColumnHeight(2,sh,ss) - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const o = vs.map(([,b,c,d,e,f,g],i) => [new Date(),Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),b,c,d,e,f,g])
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
}

function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()) { rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}
```

Comment: Dear Cooper, I’ve just copied your code to run but it can’t operate and show error “can’t read properties of null (reading ‘getRange’)”

Comment: I can't debug it with just that.  I tested it with my own data

Comment: You can use my link that i shared    at the begging, you just need to click on the button to see the error message

Comment: Sorry but I do not follow links to offsite resources

Comment: So could you share your link?

Comment: No that's exactly why I don't follow links to other google accounts.

Comment: You should be prepared to put everything need to answer the question in the question

Comment: yes, thank you for your advice